# In MS Outlook VBA, why is looping through a table five times faster than looping through the folder?

Tags: vba, search, outlook, export-to-excel, email-attachments

When I run the following code on a folder of 220 items, if `sLoopThrough` is "folder", it outputs 34 Excel rows per second, as measured by timestamps in Excel column Z when `bTimeIt` is true. When `sLoopThrough` is "table", the output jumps to 165 per second. Why is the table loop five times faster?

I would prefer the folder loop if I can speed it up because it can give me more information. For example, in the following code, the folder loop gives me the number of attachments, whereas the table can only tell me whether there are any attachments or not.

```
Sub pOutlookEmailPropertiesToExcel(sExcelPath As String, sExcelFile As String, _
                                   sExcelSheet As String, bNewFile As Boolean, _
                                   oOutlookFolder As MAPIFolder, sLoopThru As String, bTimeIt As Boolean)

' Output properties of e-mails in the given Outlook folder to Excel.

' sLoopThru = "folder" or "table"

' This code requires "Tools > References > Microsoft Excel ___ Object Library": Check.
' The workbook is opened in a new instance of Excel.

' The following line appears three times. It finds the last row with a value in column A,
'       then adds 1 to get number of the first empty row. This allows this routine to be called multiple
'       times to collect data on a series of folders (bNewFile false after first one).
'   nRowNext = oExcelSheet.Cells(oExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

' Adapted from example code at:
'   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folder.gettable
' and subs AnswerD(), AnswerF1(), AnswerF2(), and AnswerG() in SO answer by Tony Dallimore:
'   www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8697493/update-excel-sheet-based-on-outlook-mail/#8699250

Dim oExcelApp As Excel.Application, oExcelFile As Excel.Workbook, oExcelSheet As Excel.Worksheet, _
    nRowNext As Long, _
    oEmailItem As Object, nEmailItemClass As Integer, _
    oOutlookTable As Outlook.Table, oTableRow As Outlook.Row, _
    nCounter As Long

Set oExcelApp = Application.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcelApp.Visible = True         ' Dallimore: "This slows your macro but helps during debugging."
If (bNewFile) Then
    Set oExcelFile = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Add
  Else
    Set oExcelFile = oExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(sExcelPath & sExcelFile)
  End If
Set oExcelSheet = oExcelFile.Sheets(sExcelSheet)

' ***** Set up table and its columns.
If sLoopThru = "table" And (oOutlookFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem) Then
    Set oOutlookTable = oOutlookFolder.GetTable("[CreationTime] <> '0'")    ' This filter includes all.
    With oOutlookTable.Columns
        .Add ("SenderName"): .Add ("SenderEmailAddress"): .Add ("SenderEmailType"): .Add ("SentOnBehalfOfName")
        .Add ("To"): .Add ("CC"): .Add ("BCC")
        .Add ("Size"):
        .Add ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")    ' PR_HASATTACH
        ' .Add ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E13000D")    ' PR_MESSAGE_ATTACHMENTS
            ' This adds without error, but output of it is empty.
        .Add ("SentOn"): .Add ("ReceivedTime")
        .Add ("DeferredDeliveryTime"): .Add ("ReminderTime"): .Add ("ExpiryTime")
        .Add ("Unread")
      End With
  End If    ' sLoopThru = "table"

' ***** Output Excel header rows.
oExcelSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Properties of e-mail items in Outlook folder"
oExcelSheet.Range("A3:Y3").Value = _
    Array("Folder", "Subfolders", "Items", "Item", "EntryID", "MessageClass", _
          "SenderName", "SenderEmailAddress", "SenderEmailType", "SentOnBehalfOfName", _
          "To", "CC", "BCC", "Subject", "Size", "Attachments", _
          "SentOn", "ReceivedTime", "CreationTime", "LastModificationTime", _
          "DeferredDeliveryTime", "ReminderTime", "ExpiryTime", "Unread", "Error")
If (bTimeIt) Then oExcelSheet.Range("Z3").Value = "Timestamp"

' ***** Output data on folder.
nRowNext = oExcelSheet.Cells(oExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
oExcelSheet.Range("A" & nRowNext & ":C" & nRowNext).Value = _
        Array(oOutlookFolder.Name, oOutlookFolder.Folders.Count, oOutlookFolder.Items.Count)

' ***** Loop through items and output properties to Excel.
If (oOutlookFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem) Then
    Select Case sLoopThru
        Case "folder":
            For nCounter = 1 To oOutlookFolder.Items.Count
                Set oEmailItem = oOutlookFolder.Items.Item(nCounter)
                ' Dallimore tests oEmailItem.Class here, says it seems to avoid syncronisation errors.
                nRowNext = oExcelSheet.Cells(oExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                On Error GoTo ExcelError
                oExcelSheet.Range("A" & nRowNext & ":X" & nRowNext).Value = _
                    Array(oOutlookFolder.Name, , , nCounter, _
                          oEmailItem.EntryID, oEmailItem.MessageClass, _
                          oEmailItem.SenderName, oEmailItem.SenderEmailAddress, oEmailItem.SenderEmailType, _
                          oEmailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName, _
                          oEmailItem.To, oEmailItem.CC, oEmailItem.BCC, oEmailItem.Subject, _
                          oEmailItem.Size, oEmailItem.Attachments.Count, _
                          oEmailItem.SentOn, oEmailItem.ReceivedTime, oEmailItem.CreationTime, _
                          oEmailItem.LastModificationTime, oEmailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime, _
                          oEmailItem.ReminderTime, oEmailItem.ExpiryTime, oEmailItem.UnRead)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If (bTimeIt) Then oExcelSheet.Range("Z" & nRowNext).Value = Now()
              Next nCounter
        Case "table":
            nCounter = 0
            Do Until (oOutlookTable.EndOfTable)
                nCounter = nCounter + 1
                Set oTableRow = oOutlookTable.GetNextRow()
                nRowNext = oExcelSheet.Cells(oExcelSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
                On Error GoTo ExcelError
                oExcelSheet.Range("A" & nRowNext & ":X" & nRowNext).Value = _
                    Array(oOutlookFolder.Name, , , nCounter, _
                        oTableRow("EntryID"), oTableRow("MessageClass"), _
                        oTableRow("SenderName"), oTableRow("SenderEmailAddress"), oTableRow("SenderEmailType"), _
                        oTableRow("SentOnBehalfOfName"), _
                        oTableRow("To"), oTableRow("CC"), oTableRow("BCC"), oTableRow("Subject"), _
                        oTableRow("Size"), _
                        oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B"), _
                        oTableRow("SentOn"), oTableRow("ReceivedTime"), oTableRow("CreationTime"), _
                        oTableRow("LastModificationTime"), oTableRow("DeferredDeliveryTime"), _
                        oTableRow("ReminderTime"), oTableRow("ExpiryTime"), oTableRow("Unread"))
                On Error GoTo 0
                If (bTimeIt) Then oExcelSheet.Range("Z" & nRowNext).Value = Now()
              Loop
      End Select    ' sLoopThru
  End If            ' oOutlookFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem

If (bNewFile) Then
    oExcelFile.SaveAs (sExcelPath & sExcelFile)
  Else
    oExcelFile.Save
  End If
oExcelFile.Close
oExcelApp.Quit           ' Dallimore's code does this only for bNewFile true.

Exit Sub

ExcelError:
    oExcelSheet.Range("Y" & nRowNext).Value = "Error " & Err.Number & _
                                              " (" & Err.Description & ") from " & Err.Source
    Resume Next

End Sub     ' pOutlookEmailPropertiesToExcel()
```

Comment: See https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm for a discussion of what MAPI tables are

Comment: Thank you. That's very informative and helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do use tables - the data is retrieved in a single call instead of opening each item separately and retrieving one property at a time.

If you want the number of attachments, request `EntryID` and `PR_HASATTACH` (you already do that). If `PR_HASATTACH` is true, open the item by its entry id using `Namespace.GetItemFromID` and query `MailItem.Attachments.Count`.

Comment: Your page on MAPI tables linked in your comment above says that Exchange provider limits the table size to 32 kb. If I'm not using Exchange (because I'm in Windows 11), am I okay running this on a folder with 75,000 e-mails?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "If I'm not using Exchange (because I'm in Windows 11" - surely you can access a hosted Office 365 mailbox (which uses Exchange) from your Windows 11 machine?

Comment: As for the size, it mostly related to the online (no cache) mode. I don't know if Table object in OOM retrieves the data in chunks. I had to implement that in ExecSQL in Redemption.

Comment: I implemented the second paragraph of your answer by changing `oTableRow("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")` to `Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(oTableRow("EntryID")).Attachments.Count`. That changed the speed to 14 Excel rows per second, more than twice as slow as the "folder" method. Is there an efficient way to access a `MailItem` property while getting the rest of the data from a table?

Comment: I then tried moving the namespace definition to the top of the code as `Set oOutlook = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")` and then changing the code in the loop to `oOutlook.GetItem...`. That didn't help, actually dropped the speed to 13.

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for extracting attachments with tables.

Comment: I think you are missing the point - you call `GetItemFromID` / `MailItem.Attachments.Count` if and only if you have attachments (`PR_HASATTACH == true`). The assumption is that relatively few messages have attachments. If that assumption is not true in your case, you should not use the `Table` object

Comment: As for the size limitation, I can report that I have now run the code using tables on the folder with 75,000 e-mails without issue.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook's table term is very close by its nature to SQL tables. In case of cached Exchange profiles you deal with a local storage (data store). Of course, it is much faster than just iterating over all items in the folder. But it has its own minuses - only the default set of properties/data is included in the table. You can add/remove columns, but to access objects such as attachments you need to recover the real instance of the Attachments or Attachment class. The best what you could do is to the get a boolean value whether any attachment exists for the item or not. But to export data into Excel workbooks Outlook tables is exactly what you need.

If you meet an item with an attached file you need to recover an Outlook object  and then try to access the attachments. There is no other way around that unfortunately.

But if you need to search for items with attachments you may consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. They allow getting items that correspond to your search criteria and iterate over them only. You can read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)