# In MS Outlook VBA, why are properties of an e-mail reported differenly by a table than by MailItem?

Tags: vba, outlook

This question refers to the code posted in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326024/in-ms-outlook-vba-why-is-looping-through-a-table-five-times-faster-than-looping).

That routine outputs property data for the e-mails in an Outlook folder. It gets the data either directly from the `MailItem` object (`sLoopThru` = "folder") or from a [table object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table) built from the folder (`sLoopThru` = "table"). In the output of that routine, I get the following differences depending on which method is used:

- For most of the e-mails in the tested folder, the size reported by `oTableRow("Size")` is 16 bytes less than that reported by `oEmailItem.Size`.
- When a time value accessed from the table is null, such as a few of `oTableRow("SentOn")` and all of `oTableRow("ReminderTime")`, the value reported by the property directly, such as `oEmailItem.SentOn` and `oEmailItem.ReminderTime`, is 949998, which Excel automatically formats as the strange date, 4501 01 01.

The size issue is the most concerning because it's a discrepancy in the size reported for some but not all e-mails. The timestamp issue is just weird.

What is the cause of the size discrepancy and since when is the first day of the year 4501 equivalent to a null date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/1/4501 is a special date in OOM meaning there is no data, since you cannot return null from a `DateTime` property (it is scalar).

How size is reported is up to the provider - it is the size of all properties plus whatever is necessary to store those properties.

Comment: Are those two facts documented anywhere, whether on your site or elsewhere? I searched for the date and didn't find any documentation of it.

Comment: The first one is well known: https://www.google.com/search?q=1%2F1%2F4501+site%3Amicrosoft.com&client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=APwXEdeJkn9Yg-iDRd_JM3wQmgfsp1iHnQ%3A1684956659809&ei=82VuZKSFMd-kqtsPt6eGuAg&ved=0ahUKEwjkyq3Z2I7_AhVfkmoFHbeTAYcQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=1%2F1%2F4501+site%3Amicrosoft.com&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzoHCAAQHhCwAzoLCAAQCBAeEA8QsAM6BAgAEB46BQghEKABOgUIIRCrAjoICCEQFhAeEB06CgghEBYQHhAPEB1KBAhBGAFQowNYqA9gtBFoAXAAeACAAZcCiAGBC5IBBTAuNS4ymAEAoAEBoAECyAECwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1

Comment: The second one... I don't know if it is documented, it is just the way it is.

Comment: Well known by people who know it. Interesting that from that Google link, I find one link to the Outlook documentation, and it's for the `MarkAsTask` method *. Nothing about being used in `SentOn`, etc. But anyway, at least it is documented there that 4501 01 01 means null. So thank you. * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olmarkinterval